# Apply a CSS hue rotate filter to a greyscale image

Tags: html, image, css, grayscale

I am trying to work out how to change the hue of a greyscale image using CSS...

I have two images (one colour and one greyscale) and have applied this code to both:

CSS

```
img { width: 10pc; float: left; }
.huerotate { -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(300deg); }
```

HTML:

```
<img alt="Test photo: Mona Lisa" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/500px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg" class="huerotate" />

<img alt="Test photo: Hand" src="http://i821.photobucket.com/albums/zz137/ocnsamu/Capture-2.jpg" class="huerotate" />
```

This successfully changes the colour image, but the greyscale image remains unchanged.

Is there a way to change the hue of greyscale images, either using CSS another technology?

A demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ATpv8/

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do a hue rotate on grey...it's stays grey It has no 'color' as such to be `rotated`. You might try applying the `sepia` filter first and then 'rotating' that.( http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/)

Comment: for the grey one, you need to colorize it before

Comment: Thanks both, adding sepia doesn't seem to make any difference...  @GCyrillus, how would I colourize it?  Can this be done in the HTML/CSS?

Comment: maybe you can put the same image in color in background and add a little opacity to it to blend image and bg together

Comment: Until we know what it is you are **actually** trying to do it's hard to help. If you only have a greyscale image you cannot add color to specific areas. You can only colorise the whole thing and then, possibly, rotate the color ..again, of the whole thing. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ATpv8/1/

Comment: Here is what i mean : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdtFk by blending 2 images ... play with opacity on img tag

Comment: Thanks everyone, @Paulie_D 's fiddle solved the problem!  I wasn't correctly applying two filters at once, which is why it didn't work when I did tried the sepia + huerotate method.

Comment: Shall I write this up as an answer and post?  Although really the credit should go to you all for helping but don't want to make more work!  Happy to write @Paulie_D 's jsfiddle.net/ATpv8/1 up if there are no takers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As greyscale images do not contain colour by definition, a sepia filter needs to be added first to 'colourise' the greyscale photo.

From there the hue-rotate function can be applied to give a colour tint.

```
.colorme {
      -webkit-filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(300deg); 
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ATpv8/2/

Comment: Can't believe it could be done, but indeed I have made a light-green out of a white-transparent image with: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(64deg) saturate(9). It's all about the sepia. NOTE: the order matters! Sepia first!